# Реализация подписания алгоритмом ГОСТ 34.10-2012

Tags: криптография, сертификат, цифровая-подпись, криптопро

Есть система с ЭЦП, на которой было реализовано подписание с помощью алгоритма **ГОСТ Р 34.11-94**. Есть клиентская криптопро CSP 4.0 и плагин.

С 1 января 2020 года знаю, что этот алгоритм запрещают, необходимо переходить на новый **ГОСТ Р 34.10-2012**.

Я захотел получить тестовый сертификат с алгоритмом подписи **ГОСТ Р 34.10-2012** на этом тестовом [сервисе](https://testca2012.cryptopro.ru/ui/1/Login.aspx), но он вечно недоступен.

Нашел другой способ получить сертификаты [тут](https://www.cryptopro.ru/certsrv/certrqma.asp).

Получил два сертификата, один по  старому алгоритму, другой по новому

Получил в итоге вот что

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Насколько я понял, **Signature Algorithm** это поле, в котором содержится имя **алгоритма подписи**, а в **PublicKey Algorithm** содержится имя **алгоритма хэширования**.

В системе формирует сообщения без проблем, обоими сертификатами, однако, я думаю, что что-то не так. Мучают сомнения, что **алгоритм подписи** одинаковый (**ГОСТ Р 34.11-94**). Но насколько я знаю, при формировании подписи участвуют оба алгоритма, поэтому не суть важна? Правильно?

И еще, где можно получить получить тестовый сертификат с **алгоритмом подписи ГОСТ Р 34.10-2012.**. Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтобы работать с новым ГОСТ Р 34.10-2012, вам нужно прописать в конфигах клиента путь до соответствующих библиотек.

При переходе на ГОСТ Р 34.10-2012 не предполагается смена сертификата, он будет работать и со старым и с новым ГОСТ.

Comment: Но ведь подписание происходит на клиенте? CSP + плагин. О каких библиотеках идет речь?

Comment: Извиняюсь, не проверил. Да, CSP 4.0 уже работает с ГОСТ 2012. Тогда вам не стоит переживать, с 1 января вы не заметите разницы, т.к. ГОСТ Р 34.10-2012 использует схему формирования электронной подписи аналогично ГОСТ Р 34.10-2001, разница между ними в дополнительных параметрах и возможности использовать хеш-код длиной 512 бит. Если помог, выберите как ответ =)